# NHibernate Linq Group By fails to group properly in SQL Server

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I have the following LINQ query which uses NHibernate against a SQL Server backed repository...

```
var casesByCaseOwner = this.preGrantDetailRepository.All
   .Where(x => x.CaseFileLocation.Id == cflId)
   .GroupBy(x => x.CaseOwner)
   .Select(x => new StagSummaryForCfItem
   {
      Id = x.Key.Id,
      Description = x.Key.Name,
      NumberOfCases = x.Count(),
      UninvoicedNetFee = x.Sum(y => y.UninvoicedNetFee),
      UninvoicedDisbursement = x.Sum(y => y.UninvoicedDisbursement)
   }).AsEnumerable();
```

However, it complains that SQL Server is unable to group by the `CaseOwner.Name` column because it is not contained in the select list or group clause. Coming from a database world I understand that error, however, I'm not sure how to force NHibernate to group by both `Id` and `Name` but still have the `CaseOwner` entity available to me in my Select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer finally...

```
     var casesByCaseOwner = this.preGrantDetailRepository.All
     .Where(x => x.CaseFileLocation.Id == cflId)
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.CaseOwner.Id, x.CaseOwner.Name })
     .Select(x => new StagSummaryForCfItem
     {
        Id = x.Key.Id,
        Description = x.Key.Name,
        NumberOfCases = x.Count(),
        UninvoicedNetFee = x.Sum(y => y.UninvoicedNetFee),
        UninvoicedDisbursement = x.Sum(y => y.UninvoicedDisbursement)
     }).AsEnumerable();

     return casesByCaseOwner;
```

This works nicley, it turns out I need to project a new entity with the properties I want to group on.