# NotSupportedException with linq query and groupBy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I get a "NotSupportedException" when running this Linq query.  "Specified method is not supported."  What method?  Even with "Count()" commented out, the error is the same.  Null Inner Exception.

Stack Trace:

> at Hydra.WPF.ViewModels.AddressListViewModel._primaryMemberListWorker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   M:\Projects\Hydra\WPF\ViewModels\AddressList\AddressListViewModel.cs:line
>   1377 at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

The SQL Query:

```
Select * From _Members
Inner Join AddressDetailsCCN a on a.MemberId=_Members.MemberID
Inner Join 
  (
  Select Address+Address2 as CombinedAddress 
  From AddressDetailsCCN Where ListId=84 
  group by Address+Address2
  Having COUNT(*)>1
  ) B on B.CombinedAddress=A.Address+A.Address2
Where CombinedAddress is not null AND CombinedAddress!='' AND a.ListId=84
Order by ClientID, CombinedAddress
```

Linq:

```
var grouped = 
   (from mem in session.Query<Member>()
    join detail in session.Query<Detail>() on mem.Id equals detail.Member.Id
    join d2 in (from d3 in session.Query<Detail>()
                where d3.AddressList.Id == criteria.AddressList.Id
                group d3 by d3.Address + d3.Address2 into x
                where x.Count() > 1
                select x) on detail.Address+detail.Address2 equals d2.Key
    where detail.AddressList.Id==criteria.AddressList.Id
    select mem);
```

Comment: Hibernate's linq implementation has issues on basic operators. I wonder when we'll finally get a decent implementation...

Comment: 1377 is just the call to the repository method that houses this method.

Comment: you could write the same on following manner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054296/nhibernate-linq-group-by-fails-to-group-properly-in-sql-server

Comment: did you get final solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

How do you produce your criteria variable? If this is itself a deferred query or something else it sounds like the likely culprit. What happens if you do a `var criteriaId = criteria.AddressList.Id;` before your query, and provides criteriaId to your query instead of your criteria.AddressList.Id?