# Selecting an object from the GroupBy key

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm accustomed to GroupBy() being more of an art than a science, but maybe someone can help me with a very specific problem:

Given the following code

```
var results = session.Query<MyClass>()
.GroupBy(c => c.OtherPersistentObject)
.Select(group => new
{
    key = group.Key,
    count = group.Count()
})
.ToList();
```

The generated query comes out like this:

```
    /* [expression] */select
    otherclass_.ID as col_0_0_,
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_1_0_,
    otherclass_.ID as id1_1_,
    otherclass_.START_DATE as start2_1_,
    otherclass_.END_DATE as end3_1_,
    otherclass_.Zone as zone9_1_
from
    mytable mytable0_ 
left outer join
    otherclass otherclass_ 
        on mytable0_.otherID=otherclass_.ID 
group by
    mytable0_.otherID
```

which gives me the SQL error "`Column 'otherclass .ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`"

Is there a way to get the Select to do what I want?

TIA

Comment: Don't know NHibernate well enough but it seems it doesn't translate grouping by objects well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9054296/861716.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known NHibernate issue [NH-3027](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1111).

As a workaround you can use last approach described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268100/how-to-query-the-first-entry-in-each-group-in-nhibernate/57371194#57371194) (rewrite GroupBy part as sub-query). So your query can be rewritten to something like:

```
var results = session.Query<MyClass>()
        .Where(c => c == session.Query<MyClass>().First(cs => cs.OtherPersistentObject == c.OtherPersistentObject))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            key = x.OtherPersistentObject, 
            count = session.Query<MyClass>().Count(cs => cs.OtherPersistentObject == x.OtherPersistentObject)
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var results = session
    .Query<MyClass>()
    .GroupBy(c => c.OtherPersistentObject)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        key = group.Key.Id,
        count = group.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e) you can find the reason for the error.

Comment: Thank you, @core, but I would like to select the OtherPersistentObject itself, rather than its Id -- otherwise I'd have to make a separate call to get the object.